# Why does javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemTool(...) rethrow with the widest Error class instead of ServiceConfigurationError?

Tags: java, error-handling, rethrow

The method javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemTool(Class clazz, String moduleName, String className) has the following body (JDK 12):

```java
private static <T> T getSystemTool(Class<T> clazz, String moduleName, String className) {
    try {
        ServiceLoader<T> sl = ServiceLoader.load(clazz, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        for (Iterator<T> iter = sl.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            T tool = iter.next();
            if (matches(tool, moduleName))
                return tool;
        }
    } catch (ServiceConfigurationError e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't understand the reason why authors used the widest Error class instead of something like `throw new ToolProviderError(e)` or even without rethrowing at all? Any rethrow with wide error classes doesn't help to understand what is happened here without digging into the exception chain.